# Add dynamic local image to src from props

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm new to React and I've stumbled across an issue I'm unable to find answers for.

I need to pass a local image source to the src property of an img, but it needs to be passed via the props. Is there a way to achieve this for a local image (cannot use url). I've read that if you specify require, you cannot use a variable.

I assume I may have to use webpack to resolve this but I'm unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, fyi - require is not React API, its commonjs api, mostly used in node.js
Second - It seems you are presenting two problems:

1. Using local image, without using URL. Well, javascript is not compiled to a dll like other languages/frameworks, it's a script language. Therefore, you cannot embed an image to your system. However, you can create a folder in your dist folder (also can be created by webpack build), which will contain your assets - such as an image. Then, you can import it to your code through relative URL. If its in the JSX, so you can import it like you import any other package, with the relative path. If its css, you may use the url(...) syntax.
2. Passing the url through props - just like everything else. You mention in the component reference the field you want to use as prop field, lets say "image", and inside the component you can use this.props.image. Using either simple string there or an imported "object" like mentioned above - will behave perfectly the same, and you can use it in img src field.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your help. One thing I'm still unclear about is that I have an images folder within the project, and I can reference a relative path path for the image using Import ok, but I cannot reference it directly within the src (without using 'require'). So I must use webpack (and alter the config file to allow this)?